# Can't access data from json-p call

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, getjson

I am trying to access some data from my server inside another domain.

So i have this php code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$callback = $_GET[callback];
echo $callback . '(' . $CIPHERDATA . ')';
```

The javascript that runs on the client side is this

```
$.getJSON("http://mydomain.gr/zerobin-015/?24c3285?callback=?",function(jsondata){
    alert(jsondata.data);
    alert("hi");
});
```

The alerts don't show up.
The only thing that happen's is the creation of a script tag that has all the information i need but i can't access.

```
<script src="http://mydomain.gr/zerobin-015/?24c3285?callback=jsonp1335048265855&_=1335048265874">
({"data":"{\"iv\":\"smDkNQMt0MIbPABPbAb+xQ\",\"salt\":\"aoFfKV+jHhs\",\"ct\":\"Ns17UQZQN\/ktO2hUW+dPug\"}","meta":{"expire_date":1337635538,"postdate":1335043538}})
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with my json-p format?
What is the proper format of this data so they are accesible?

Comment: Should the jsonp data that is returned be in the format above:       
({"data":"{\"iv\":\"smDkNQMt0MIbPABPbAb+xQ\",\"salt\":\"aoFfKV+jHhs\",\"ct\":\"Ns17UQZQN\/ktO2hUW+dPug\"}","meta":{"expire_date":1337635538,"postdate":1335043538}})
                or should it be like this:     ([{"data":"{\"iv\":\"smDkNQMt0MIbPABPbAb+xQ\",\"salt\":\"aoFfKV+jHhs\",\"ct\":\"Ns17UQZQN\/ktO2hUW+dPug\"}","meta":{"expire_date":1337635538,"postdate":1335043538,"remaining_time":2544592}}])

Comment: maybe.  Maybe not.  The data in that example is a jsonified string. It seems to me, that double-level of jsonification is unnecessary.

Comment: what do you mean jsonified string?how those data should be to be understandable by jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the data format.The json string that should be served by php is:
 {"data":"{"iv":"smDkNQMt0MIbPABPbAb+xQ","salt":"aoFfKV+jHhs","ct":"Ns17UQZQNktO2hUW+dPug"}","meta":{"expire_date":1337635538,"postdate":1335043538}}

The mistake at the php code that i use json_encode two times on the same string.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right.
It's just a runtime error in the PHP.
In your PHP script, replace `$GET[callback]` with `$GET['callback']`.  Note the single-quotes.

**EDIT**

Looking at your URL, I'd say you also need to replace this:

```
http://mydomain.gr/zerobin-015/?24c3285?callback=?
```

with this:

```
http://mydomain.gr/zerobin-015/?24c3285&callback=?
```

Note: the second ? gets replaced with &.  According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the format of HTTP URLs calls for at most one ? in any URL.  This situation may be a little confusing because of the trailing ? .  That one gets replaced by jQuery at runtime in the `$.getJSON()` call.  That final ? will not appear in the final URL. So in the end you should have just one ? .

---

**EDIT 2**

I just tried an HTTP GET on your jsonp endpoint.  Here's the URL I used:

```
http://kasem.gr/vasilis-dev/zerobin-015/?xxxxxBigStringHerexxxx=&callback=foo
```

The `xxxxBigStringHerexxx` was replaced with a string of 40 apparently random characters and digits. The result I got:

```
jsonCallback({"data":"{\"iv\":\"smDkNQMt0MIbPABPbAb+xQ\",
                       \"salt\":\"aoFfKV+jHhs\",\"ct\":\"Ns17UQZQN\/ktO2hUW+dPug\"}",
              "meta":{"expire_date":1337635538,"postdate":1335043538}})
```

This tells me your PHP is incorrect. It is using `jsonCallback` as the callback function name, when I passed "foo".  Also, for some reason the "data" is a serialized json string. This seems an un-necessary step.  But the function mismatch is of primary importance.

If this is not clear, I suggest that you [read a little more about JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: I made both changes you said but still the success function doesn't work and i can't access the data inside json with jsondata.data or jsondata.meta

Comment: i have made a fiddle with my real code.you need firebug to to see inside the iframe's head the <script> tag that is created.For a weird reason the script only works with jquery 1.3.2. http://jsfiddle.net/3yZvu/

Comment: re: *for a weird reason* ... what's the reason it works only with back-revs of jquery?  Do you know the reason or do you mean to imply "for some *unknown* reason" ?

Comment: 1.The "jsonCallback" was there because i was experimenting with my php code at the time you tried it.Try it now and you'll see there is no "jsonCallback".2.I dont know the reason why it only works with back-revs.I suppose they changed the strictness of json format.3.When the request is with callback=foo at the end what the result should be?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the server is getting the wrong request header and therefore not returning the JSON response as part of the success statement. I bet if you add a catch for the error in the AJAX call you'll see the JSONP response there. The correct way to fix this is to ensure you are sending the correct mimetype headers to the server so that the returning JSONP callback is called within the correct context.

Comment: this made the script to create a script tag on chrome with the json inside.But still the alert commands dont work.And i can't access the data inside the json with jsondata.data or jsondata.meta

Comment: What i did is i changed the php header to "header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');"  on php.I think that's what you meant.